# C++ encapsulation, how is it useful

Tags: c++, class, encapsulation

The following slide refers to C++ language and it says that

> "encapsulation is about ensuring the user uses our ADT in a safe way"

But, If he have access to my .h files he can edit it for example and change what was declared inside my class from private to public.

for example:

my_file.h:

```
class Complex {
private:
    double re, im;
public:
    double get_re();
};
```

then the user could write: (after changing from private to public)

```
Complex s1;
s1.re=13;
```

Please Click the following link to view the image (Since I don't have point to include images):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOj5E.jpg)

Comment: The objective is to make it harder to make a mistake. You can't make it impossible. No matter how you foolproof a system, there will always be a better fool, so you might as well spend your effort elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++ you can shoot into your foot in a lot of ways. You can also use

```
#define private public
```

and you won't need to change anything in the code to access the private interface... the point here is not how encapsulation can be broken, instead is about what you achieve using that.

When you have to choose between `class` and `struct`, you have to think if what you are going to represent with that, and if that thing has an invariant, then you should use a class, otherwise a struct: encapsulation will let you achieve that "invariant" using encapsulation, and so letting the user access the data, or set/modify the data only using public interfaces you have defined, and not how he wants.

For example, if you define a class `Date`, you have an invariant like "max 31 as day, max 12 as month ...", but if you want to define for example `DifferenceInDays`, which will have just an `int` for the `days`, than you can allow user to read and write whatever he wants in that struct, because you don't have any invariant

Comment: `You can also use #define private public` "can" in the sense that doing so technically results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: so if I understand correctly the user can always find a way to break the restriction of private, but we use it anyway to let him know that it's better not to access that value directly, right?

Comment: The **only** difference between `struct` and `class` is default access. If there is no access specifier, the members of a `struct` are public, and the members of a `class` are private; similarly, if there is no access specifier for a base, a `struct` inherits that base publicly, and a `class` inherits it privately.

Comment: @PeteBecker But that isn't my question, kindly read my sum-up two comments before

Comment: @clark_smith1 — I wasn’t answering your question. I was commenting on the answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker what you mentioned isn't precise, there are other differences as I read before: "When deriving a struct from a class/struct, default access-specifier for a base class/struct is public. And when deriving a class, default access specifier is private."

Comment: @clark_smith1 yes, here the point is not the security it provides you seen as "secure code", but instead "safe code", and so without any """strange""" behavior  (or bad defined behavior, like if you would have a date with 14 as month)

Comment: @clark_smith1 Pete's comment is precise. When inheriting a base, whether the base is struct or class is irrelevant. Pete's comment describes how the struct / class keyword affects the access of the base in case of no access specifier.

Comment: @eerorika sorry, i'm from italy, so my english is not that great, feel free to edit the question, i'll accept it with no problem

Comment: @PeteBecker with your first comment, were you commenting my question? i know the "implementation" differences between class and struct, however my point was that encapsulation in class (and also in struct, if you specify the accessor) is made to maintain a invariant, and encapsulation  gives you this possibility

Comment: @PeteBecker with this, i'm not saying that you can't achieve encapsulation in struct, but i wasn't trying to explain what's the difference between class and struct, but what's an invariant and then that encapsulation gives you the possibility to achieve it

Comment: A `class` and a `struct` can both be used to represent types with an invariant in exactly the same way. That is not a basis for choosing between them. People often use `struct` to represent plain data, because that's the C heritage, but there is no language-level reason for doing that; it's just a convention.

Comment: @PeteBecker as guidelines says, you should use class if you want to make clear that behind that there is an invariant, good reading https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-class

Comment: That's not what your answer says. "if that thing has an invariant, then you should use a class, otherwise a struct: encapsulation will let you achieve that "invariant" using encapsulation" pretty strongly implies that only classes support encapsulation. That is simply wrong. Further, there are many things other than having an invariant that benefit from encapsulation.